# php exec() responding differently from windows 8 metro app

Tags: php, cmd, exec, windows-8

I wanted to change the tile icons for desktop applications in the new windows 8 start menu.
So they would fit in with the other metro apps.

I made a simple metro app that calls a simple localhost php file

```
<?php 

// check if the chrome is in the task list
exec('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "chrome.exe">NUL');
// get a return value I can check
$runing = exec('if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Programm is running');

if ($runing === 'Programm is running'){
        // the program is open already
        echo $runing;
} else {
        // the program is not running and should be opened
        exec('C:\Users\Gerdy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe');
}

?>
```

If I launch this file from chrome it echos "Programm is running".

That's great!

If I launch it from windows start and Chrome is not running, Chrome does not start.

If I exclude the if statement and just run.

```
exec('C:\Users\Gerdy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe');
```

From the start menu.
It will open a new Chrome window regardless of if chrome is already open.

So I guess my question is :
What can I do that will allow my php file to check if chrome is open and if it is not , to open it?

This model actually works for any other program just not browsers.

My best guess is that it has do less with my commands and more to do with chrome itself.
It could be a target that I need to add, I don't know.

Comment: Complete guess but does using shell_exec help at all?

Comment: Adding shell_ did not affect behavior. I have found that this script works as intended for all other programs just not browsers. I think that is likely an issue with my TASKLIST check. I know that chrome runs several processes, that may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can use Windows Management Instrumentation:

If you have not used `wmic` before you should install it by running `wmic` from `cmd.exe`.
It should then say something like:

```
WMIC Installing... please wait.
```

After that `wmic` is ready for use:

```
function getProcessId( $imagename ) {
    ob_start();
    passthru('wmic process where (name="'.$imagename.'") get ProcessId');
    $wmic_output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    // Remove everything but numbers and commas between numbers from output:
    $wmic_output = preg_replace( 
        array('/[^0-9\n]*/','/[^0-9]+\n|\n$/','/\n/'), 
        array('','',','), 
        $wmic_output );
    if ($wmic_output != '') {
        // WMIC returned valid PId, should be safe to convert to int:
        $wmic_output = explode(',', $pids);
        foreach ($wmic_output as $k => $v) { $wmic_output[$k] = (int)$v; }
        return $wmic_output;
    } else {
        // WMIC did not return valid PId
        return false;
    }
}

// Find out process id's:
if ($pids = getProcessId( "chrome.exe" )) {
    foreach ($pids as $pid) {
        echo "Chrome.exe is running with pid $pid";
    }
} else {
    echo "Chrone.exe is not running";
}
```

I have not tested this and just wrote it out of my head so there might be some fixing and you should check wmic's output by running it from commandline with same args to see if `preg_replace()` is doing it right (get pid from wmic's output).

#### UPDATE:

Tested and it seems that `wmic` does not return any status codes so updated my php function to reflect this bahavior.

#### UPDATE:

Now it handles multiple processes too and returns all pids as indexed array or false when no process running.

#### About WMI:

Windows Management Instrumentation is very powerful interface and so is `wmic` commandline tool. [Here is listed some of WMI features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation#Features)

Comment: Thank you. I am admittedly a novice. I didn't know 'wmic' existed. and this answer is concise, complete and informative.

Comment: I forgot to remove unneccesary `$result` variable, it can be removed from `passthru(...)` as `wmic` does not return any real status code so there is no use for `%errorlevel%` with `wmic`.

Comment: Thank you, unnecessary variable removed.